# increment the setInterval timer on every execution

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In my implementation ,method is executed every 5 sec. But I want to increment the time interval in series . First run at 5th sec , second run at 15th sec , third run at 30th sec . the below code is still executing every 5 sec . Can someone help to resolve the issue

```
    var timer = 5000;
   var win = setInterval( callback,timer);
        function callback () {
                    timesRun += 1;

                    if (totalResultUpdated > totalResultInitial)
                    {
                        clearInterval(win);
                          timer*=2;
                        fun(false);
                    } 
                              win=setInterval(callback,timer);
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just set `timer` to another value. Once an interval is started, it will continue with the time it was set to initially. Instead of starting an interval i would recommend to use a pseudorecursive timeout instead:

```
 function increasingInterval(fn, time) {
   function next(i) {
     fn();
     setTimeout(next, time * i, i + 1);
   }
   setTimeout(next, time, 2);
 }
```

So you can do:

```
 increasingInterval(function() {
   console.log("something");
 }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let timeout = 5000;

let intervalId = setInterval(callback, timeout);
function callback () {
  console.log('Do something here', new Date());
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  timeout *= 2;
  intervalId = setInterval(callback, timeout);
}
```

Comment: i modified the code as mentioned above with your approach. Still it fails.can u pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a recursion for this :

```js
function setIncrementalInterval(fn, initTime, incr){
            setTimeout(fn,initTime)
            setTimeout(function(){setIncrementalInterval(fn, initTime+incr, incr)},initTime)

}


let time = Date.now()

function myFunction(){
      console.log(Date.now()-time)
}

setIncrementalInterval(myFunction,1000,1000)
```

here initial delay is 1000ms and increments by 1000ms